# jQuery - Get children from index as jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

`[]` and `.get()` both return a collection element at the given index but as a native DOM element. How can i do if i want to retrieve it as a jQuery object ? I'm forced to convert their return value using $() everytime like :

```
var $third = $($elements.get(3));
```

And it gets even more horrible if i have to nest it.
Is there some kinf of `.at()` method that would be used this way :

```
var $third = $elements.at(3);
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try using $elements.eq(index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `.eq()`

```
var $third = $elements.eq(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you try  `$('.selector:eq(index)')`

Comment: Thanks for your help. .eq() seems more optimized though.